# LoadRunner recording on ODBC protocol for sybase?

Tags: odbc, sybase, record, loadrunner

I am trying to record datasource for sybase server, I am using ODBC protocol but the problem is once VuGen launch the application for recording nothing is coming up I mean VuGen is not able to record. I am selecting Rapid SQL.exe file. For ODBC do I need to select any other file??

Answer (score 0):

Architecturally, how do you know that the application is using ODBC for connectivity and it's using the "right version" of ODBC?   You may need another method.

Comment: I found it in protocol advisor.

Comment: And you confirmed this in the application how?   Design documents?   Setup guide?   Setup requirements (which specifically call out ODBC)? ????   Each of the recommendations of the protocol advisor need to be matched to observations and known information about the application.  It probably also mentioned dcom and winsock as well, which would have been poor decisions.

Comment: But what does the architecture guide for your application suggest?   What does the installation guide suggest?  What does Wireshark suggest when you scope the conversation?   What are you using to measure the recommendations against to test their veracity in your environment?